# How is this function derived from the sifting property of the delta function?

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta

From a book on imaging:

> Using the sifting property of the $2D$ continuous impulse:
>
> $$\int \int f(t,z)\delta(t-t_0, z-z_0) dt dz=f(t_0,z_0)$$
>
> We can write a function $f(x,y)$ as:
> $$f(x,y) = \int \int f(a,b) \delta (x-a, y-b)\space da \space db$$

Can someone explain how the second formula can be derived from the first formula?  I've been trying to figure a way to show this and nothing I've tried yielded any results.

Comment: The second formula is essentially the first modulo a change of variables.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Can you explain how to derive it?  I don't understand what you mean by "modulo a change of variables".

Answer (score 0):

The delta function is separable in each of its variable so $\delta(x,y) = \delta(x)\delta(y)$ (think about why this makes sense). Plugging this into the formula we have
$$\begin{align*}
f(t_0, z_0) &=\int \int f(t, z)\delta(t-t_0, z-z_0)dt dz\\
&=\int \delta(z-z_0)\left(\int f(t, z)\delta(t-t_0)dt\right) dz\\
&=\int f(t_0, z)\delta(z-z_0) dz\\ 
&=f(t_0, z_0)
\end{align*}
$$

Where the second line uses the separability of the Dirac delta, the third uses the sifting property of a 1D Dirac Delta, and the last line again uses the sifting property